# Attribute restrictions on C# generics

Tags: c#, generics, attributes

I have the following method declaration:

```
public static bool SerializeObject<T>(string filename, T objectToSerialize){
```

I want to restrict `T` to types decorated with the `[Serializable]` attribute.

The following does not work because "Attribute 'System.SerializableAttribute' is not valid on this declaration type. It is valid on 'Class, Enum, Struct, Delegate' declarations only.":

```
public static bool SerializeObject<T>(string filename, [Serializable] T objectToSerialize)
```

I understand that `AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Parameter)` must be set for the Attribute in order to use the above and that the `[Serializable]` attribute does not have this set.

Is there a way to restrict `T` to types marked with the `[Serializable]` attribute?

Comment: Can you restrict on an interface?  That seems like the natural way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way to restrict `T` to types marked with the `[Serializable]` attribute?

No, there is not a way to do this using generic constraints. These contraints are clearly spelled out in the specification and this is not one of them.

However, you could write an extension method

```
public static bool IsTypeSerializable(this Type type) {
    Contract.Requires(type != null);
    return type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SerializableAttribute), true)
               .Any();
}
```

and say

```
Contract.Requires(typeof(T).IsTypeSerializable());
```

No, it's not the same thing, but it's the best that you can do. The constraints on generics are fairly limited.

Lastly, you could consider saying

```
where T : ISerializable
```

Again, not the same thing, but it's something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, you cannot create a generic constraint that checks attributes.  The best you can do would be to implement the constraint at runtime:

```
if (!typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SerializableAttribute), true).Any())
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply throw a an exception so that the programmer knows it has to be Serializable.

like so:

```
public static bool SerializeObject<T>(string filename, T objectToSerialize)
{
    if(!typeof(objectToSerialize).IsSerializable)
    {
              throw new Exception("objectToSerialize is not serializable");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You can however restrict the type to implement `ISerializable` which isn't the same as a decorating with `SerializableAttribute`, however.

Answer (score 0):

No. Attributes are not constraints, but are information added to metadata.
You can test if the attribute has been set with:

```
If(typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SerializableAttribute), false).Length == 0) {
    throw new ...
}
```

The Boolean parameter determines if inherited attributes are to be considered or not.