# How to require Serializable Object as method parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization

```
public void myMethod('SerializableObject' obj);
```

The code above is an example to let you understand. 
If I want that the Object given as parameter of myMethod() is certainly Serializable, what can I do?
Are there interfaces implemented by every Serializable class?

In Java, I used to do as you can see below :

```
public void myMethod(Serializable obj)
```

How can I do this in C# ?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910949/attribute-restrictions-on-c-sharp-generics) might have some helpful information

Comment: this is a dup of the linked question - short answer is "no"; in addition to other concerns, "serializable" is a very loose topic and depends on your choice of serializer - the only thing that `[Serializable]` applies to is `BinaryFormatter`, which I *strongly advise against using*